# Error Getting tweets from Twitter api 1.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter

I've followed an online tutorial from here: http://www.webdevdoor.com/javascript-ajax/custom-twitter-feed-integration-jquery/

But I'm getting an error message which simply states 'error: ' and nothing else.

First of all my php script to call the JSON output is as follows:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php"); //Path to twitteroauth library

$twitteruser = "abstractweb";
$notweets = 3;
$consumerkey = "S1WEUELXXbm3XMXKOw";
$consumersecret = "p7Z7ftlJoqATxMlRHkmQWjemsr7Cof96oXhz2Vqb4E";
$accesstoken = "192370815-O6LUMwpf3D1S4zZpQXobL6GPxLc4AFFSwg5yknxU";
$accesstokensecret = "n0fDCtsQFxKJss6tpASeOrq9MluMPdGufNbi1Vs";

function getConnectionWithAccessToken($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret) {
  $connection = new TwitterOAuth($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
  return $connection;
}

$connection = getConnectionWithAccessToken($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);

$tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$twitteruser."&count=".$notweets);

echo json_encode($tweets);
?>
```

And the JQuery to call this is:

```
// JavaScript Document
//JQuery Twitter Feed. Coded by Tom Elliott @ www.webdevdoor.com (2013) based on https://twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js
//Requires JSON output from authenticating script: http://www.webdevdoor.com/php/authenticating-twitter-feed-timeline-oauth/

$(document).ready(function () {
    var displaylimit = 3;
    var twitterprofile = "abstractweb";
    var screenname = "Abstract Web";
    var showdirecttweets = false;
    var showretweets = true;
    var showtweetlinks = true;
    var showprofilepic = false;
    var showtweetactions = true;
    var showretweetindicator = true;

    var headerHTML = '';
    var loadingHTML = '';
    headerHTML += '<a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank"><img src="images/twitter-bird-light.png" width="34" style="float:left;padding:3px 12px 0px 6px" alt="twitter bird" /></a>';
    headerHTML += '<h1>'+screenname+' <span style="font-size:13px"><a href="https://twitter.com/'+twitterprofile+'" target="_blank">@'+twitterprofile+'</a></span></h1>';
    loadingHTML += '<div id="loading-container"><img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" width="32" height="32" alt="tweet loader" /></div>';

    $('#twitter-feed').html(headerHTML + loadingHTML);

    $.getJSON('http://www.abstract-thinking.co.uk/get-tweets1.php', 
        function(feeds) {   
           //alert(feeds);
            var feedHTML = '';
            var displayCounter = 1;         
            for (var i=0; i<feeds.length; i++) {
                var tweetscreenname = feeds[i].user.name;
                var tweetusername = feeds[i].user.screen_name;
                var profileimage = feeds[i].user.profile_image_url_https;
                var status = feeds[i].text; 
                var isaretweet = false;
                var isdirect = false;
                var tweetid = feeds[i].id_str;

                //If the tweet has been retweeted, get the profile pic of the tweeter
                if(typeof feeds[i].retweeted_status != 'undefined'){
                   profileimage = feeds[i].retweeted_status.user.profile_image_url_https;
                   tweetscreenname = feeds[i].retweeted_status.user.name;
                   tweetusername = feeds[i].retweeted_status.user.screen_name;
                   tweetid = feeds[i].retweeted_status.id_str;
                   status = feeds[i].retweeted_status.text; 
                   isaretweet = true;
                 };


                 //Check to see if the tweet is a direct message
                 if (feeds[i].text.substr(0,1) == "@") {
                     isdirect = true;
                 }

                //console.log(feeds[i]);

                 //Generate twitter feed HTML based on selected options
                 if (((showretweets == true) || ((isaretweet == false) && (showretweets == false))) && ((showdirecttweets == true) || ((showdirecttweets == false) && (isdirect == false)))) { 
                    if ((feeds[i].text.length > 1) && (displayCounter <= displaylimit)) {             
                        if (showtweetlinks == true) {
                            status = addlinks(status);
                        }

                        if (displayCounter == 1) {
                            feedHTML += headerHTML;
                        }

                        feedHTML += '<div class="twitter-article">';                                                         
                        feedHTML += '<div class="twitter-pic"><a href="https://twitter.com/'+tweetusername+'" target="_blank"><img src="'+profileimage+'"images/twitter-feed-icon.png" width="42" height="42" alt="twitter icon" /></a></div>';
                        feedHTML += '<div class="twitter-text"><p><span class="tweetprofilelink"><strong><a href="https://twitter.com/'+tweetusername+'" target="_blank">'+tweetscreenname+'</a></strong> <a href="https://twitter.com/'+tweetusername+'" target="_blank">@'+tweetusername+'</a></span><span class="tweet-time"><a href="https://twitter.com/'+tweetusername+'/status/'+tweetid+'" target="_blank">'+relative_time(feeds[i].created_at)+'</a></span><br/>'+status+'</p>';

                        if ((isaretweet == true) && (showretweetindicator == true)) {
                            feedHTML += '<div id="retweet-indicator"></div>';
                        }                       
                        if (showtweetactions == true) {
                            feedHTML += '<div id="twitter-actions"><div class="intent" id="intent-reply"><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?in_reply_to='+tweetid+'" title="Reply"></a></div><div class="intent" id="intent-retweet"><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/retweet?tweet_id='+tweetid+'" title="Retweet"></a></div><div class="intent" id="intent-fave"><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/favorite?tweet_id='+tweetid+'" title="Favourite"></a></div></div>';
                        }

                        feedHTML += '</div>';
                        feedHTML += '</div>';
                        displayCounter++;
                    }   
                 }
            }

            $('#twitter-feed').html(feedHTML);

            //Add twitter action animation and rollovers
            if (showtweetactions == true) {             
                $('.twitter-article').hover(function(){
                    $(this).find('#twitter-actions').css({'display':'block', 'opacity':0, 'margin-top':-20});
                    $(this).find('#twitter-actions').animate({'opacity':1, 'margin-top':0},200);
                }, function() {
                    $(this).find('#twitter-actions').animate({'opacity':0, 'margin-top':-20},120, function(){
                        $(this).css('display', 'none');
                    });
                });         

                //Add new window for action clicks

                $('#twitter-actions a').click(function(){
                    var url = $(this).attr('href');
                  window.open(url, 'tweet action window', 'width=580,height=500');
                  return false;
                });
            }


    }).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if (errorThrown == "Not Found") {
            errorThrown = "not found: tweets php script";   
        }
       alert(textStatus + " - " + errorThrown);
    });


    //Function modified from Stack Overflow
    function addlinks(data) {
        //Add link to all http:// links within tweets
         data = data.replace(/((https?|s?ftp|ssh)\:\/\/[^"\s\<\>]*[^.,;'">\:\s\<\>\)\]\!])/g, function(url) {
            return '<a href="'+url+'" >'+url+'</a>';
        });

        //Add link to @usernames used within tweets
        data = data.replace(/\B@([_a-z0-9]+)/ig, function(reply) {
            return '<a href="http://twitter.com/'+reply.substring(1)+'" style="font-weight:lighter;" target="_blank">'+reply.charAt(0)+reply.substring(1)+'</a>';
        });
        //Add link to #hastags used within tweets
        data = data.replace(/\B#([_a-z0-9]+)/ig, function(reply) {
            return '<a href="https://twitter.com/search?q='+reply.substring(1)+'" style="font-weight:lighter;" target="_blank">'+reply.charAt(0)+reply.substring(1)+'</a>';
        });
        return data;
    }


    function relative_time(time_value) {
      var values = time_value.split(" ");
      time_value = values[1] + " " + values[2] + ", " + values[5] + " " + values[3];
      var parsed_date = Date.parse(time_value);
      var relative_to = (arguments.length > 1) ? arguments[1] : new Date();
      var delta = parseInt((relative_to.getTime() - parsed_date) / 1000);
      var shortdate = time_value.substr(4,2) + " " + time_value.substr(0,3);
      delta = delta + (relative_to.getTimezoneOffset() * 60);

      if (delta < 60) {
        return '1m';
      } else if(delta < 120) {
        return '1m';
      } else if(delta < (60*60)) {
        return (parseInt(delta / 60)).toString() + 'm';
      } else if(delta < (120*60)) {
        return '1h';
      } else if(delta < (24*60*60)) {
        return (parseInt(delta / 3600)).toString() + 'h';
      } else if(delta < (48*60*60)) {
        //return '1 day';
        return shortdate;
      } else {
        return shortdate;
      }
    }

});
```

Something else to note is that I'm running this in ASP.NET VB application, don't know if that makes a difference.

I'm totally stumped, can anyone see something I can't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
require_once("twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php"); //Path to twitteroauth library
```

Path was incorrect to twitteroauth.php file